# extract merge and create a new column from two dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data frame like these.

A:

```
   A1 A2
1:  a  e
2:  b  f
3:  c  g
4:  d  h
```

B:

```
        B1  B2
1:       a   1
2: b,i,j,k   2
3:     a,q 3,4
4:       e 4,5
5:   c,d,f   6
```

Once A1 belongs to B1, I want to create a new column A3 use the info B2 like this

```
  A3
1 1,3,4
2     2
3     6
4     6
```

Comment: You should work on making this more easily reproduced, like so we can copy paste something directly into R. I usually use `dput(setDF(A))` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop across `A$A1` with `sapply`, using `grep` to pull out the row index of `B1` with a match, and use that to subset `B2`:

```
A$A3 <- sapply(A$A1, function(x){paste(B$B2[grep(x, B$B1)], collapse = ',')})

A
##    A1 A2    A3
## 1:  a  e 1,3,4
## 2:  b  f     2
## 3:  c  g     6
## 4:  d  h     6
```

or in data.table notation,

```
A[, A3 := sapply(A1, function(x){B[grep(x, B1), paste(B2, collapse = ',')]})][]
```